# How to use workspace mapping from two projects in a build

Tags: build, azure-devops, devops

Is it possible to have a workspace mapping that includes paths from two projects in Builds in DevOps?

I have created this mapping in a build in ProjectOne that includes a path from ProjectTwo, but when running the build it will only map the files from ProjectOne:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's supported.

Just try to specify the `Local path under $(build.sourcesDirectory)`.

Tested on my side, everything works as expected.

[image]